# Python gzip module doesn't work as expected on ubyte file

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, gunzip

I expected the following code

```
import gzip
import numpy as np

def read_ubyte(self, fname):
    with gzip.open(fname, 'rb') as flbl:
        magic, num = struct.unpack(">II", flbl.read(8))
        lbl = np.fromfile(flbl, dtype=np.int8)
    return magic, num, lbl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(read_ubyte("train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"))
```

to work exactly the same as first doing `gunzip train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz` then executing

```
import numpy as np

def read_ubyte(self, fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as flbl:
        magic, num = struct.unpack(">II", flbl.read(8))
        lbl = np.fromfile(flbl, dtype=np.int8)
    return magic, num, lbl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(read_ubyte("train-labels-idx1-ubyte"))
```

but it doesn't, the first code gives output:

```
(2049, 60000, array([  0,   3, 116, ..., -22,   0,   0], dtype=int8))
```

and the second

```
(2049, 60000, array([5, 0, 4, ..., 5, 6, 8], dtype=int8))
```

**Why?**

*note 1: the second is the right output (with no `gzip` module usage)*

*note 2: the numbers 2049 and 60000 are right*

*note 3: If you want to reproduce, you can download the file at http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy and GZip disagree about file object semantics.  This is a [known issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1103), which some parts of NumPy (like `np.load()`) accommodate, but `fromfile()` does not.

To work around it (only needed in the `gzip` case, but works in both):

```
    lbl = np.fromstring(flbl.read(), dtype=np.int8)
```